# ZeroMQ PULL service not scaling, doesn't close connections

Tags: php, c++, linux, zeromq

The challenge is to simply copy and PUSH several hundred http requests/sec from PHP to a single C++ PULL server. The PULL server simply writes the request to STDOUT.

Under load, the system handles the load until the PULL server exhausts its open file limit of 10,000, then it stops accepting connections and pegs itself at 100% CPU usage.

The meat of the server looks like this (with all the error catching code removed:)

```
// Crank up zmq
ctx = zmq_ctx_new ();

// Pull socket type in the pipeline pattern
s = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_PULL);
rc = zmq_bind (s, socketdsn);

// Create a buffer to store messages
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER] = {0};
while (true) {
    // Get the message
    rc = zmq_recv (s, buffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0);

    // Tack a null at the end of the string so printf will work...
    buffer[rc] = 0;

    // Output the string.
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
rc = zmq_close (s);
rc = zmq_term (ctx);
```

The meat of the PHP PUSH server looks like this:

```
$dsn = "tcp://localhost:5555";
// Create context
$ctx = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $ctx->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my socket');
$socket->connect($dsn, true);
$rc = $socket->send($message);
$socket->close($dsn);
```

My guess is that the PULL server must manually close it's connection after a message is received. The PUSH client being a PHP process, the PULL server will never see another message from it and closing the connection is safe. But there doesn't appear to be an appropriate function for that. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the problem, create the PHP context without persistence: $ctx = new ZMQContext(1, false);

Comment: PHP in question is running behind Apache/Nginx or is it a CLI thing?